Gray screen when opening Flutter Web
I have a Flutter Web app for Telegram Mini Apps. And it works fine for me, everything opens fine. But many of my users get a gray screen:

And this has been going on for quite some time. Although when I update files on the server, the site is updated and appears updated on my PC, laptop and phone, but users still see a gray screen.
This is what my nginx config looks like on the server, if you need it:

How can this be fixed?

ig you wanted to have fileName.json

Your file has no name, there should be a name for that file like ../translation/test.json

There are two files in the translations folder, both of which have names.

I think you are calling for a file with no name

IDK what is in your assets folder, but keep in mind that NGINX keep cache for a long time, so sometimes you may need wait
